# How can I create a contained user on an Azure SQL database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to create a contained user for my Azure SQL database using C#. I have the following code already for creating the database:

```
// Login to Azure
var credentials = UserTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(clientId, domainName, username, password).Result;

// Create client
SqlManagementClient client = new SqlManagementClient(credentials)
{
    SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
};

// Database parameters
var databaseParameters = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models.Database()
{
    Location = "ukwest",
    ElasticPoolId = elasticPoolId,

};

// Create database
var dbResponse = client.Databases.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, serverName, databaseName, databaseParameters);
```

I have found the following SQL script that can be used to create a contained user using SQL management studio but this requires that you manually connect to the database that you want to create the user for:

```
CREATE USER [databaseUser] WITH PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [databaseUser]
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [databaseUser]
```

So how can I use the SQL script within my C# code to connect the database after it has been created to then create the contained SQL user for that database, or is there some equivalent code available in **Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.SqlManagementClient** for doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually, you should think about Azure SQL Database as having (at least) 2 different layers at which you can operate:

- There is a REST API for control operations such as creating a database, changing its reservation size, restoring a copy, etc.
- There is a T-SQL interface for operations within a database container, from creating tables to inserting rows, etc.

There can be some overlap across these two surfaces - in traditional SQL Server, all of it is exposed in the latter T-SQL interface.  Some of those commands are enabled in Azure SQL Database and they are internally calling the REST API for you.

Note that operations to the REST API use the credentials associated with Azure's Portal infrastructure.  Within the database, you can have mappings into SQL logins/users, but you can also have SQL logins/users that are not associated at all with the Azure identities.

Net-net: you should connect to the database using the C# SQLClient and run those commands using an authenticated user with enough permissions (in your case, likely the administrator account or sa) to get the new user and role information set up.

[Here's a an example on how to set up C# SQLClient](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient)

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. I found the following example for using SQLClient with an Azure database which is a bit more readable and also specifies how to connect to an Azure database: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet-visual-studio